# simple loop used to be fast, now it's slow

Tags: vba, loops

I have a simple piece of code that used to burn through 45,000 rows of data in the blink of an eye and now it takes a very long time (~15 minutes).  I have read through some similar problems but wanted to post the code since it is so basic.  This code sums the individual weights of each item (one item per row) of an order and then populates a cell for each item with the total amount.  It goes from top to bottom to get the total and then from bottom to top filling in the blanks.  What am I missing?

```
Sub FillInTotalWeight()
'
' sort whole file by process order

'
'this macro sums all the children weights in a process order
'and then puts that total in column E for every child of the process order
'

Dim nLastRow As Long
Dim nRow As Long
Dim wtTot As Long
Dim nStop As Long

'
'determine the last row
'
nLastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'
'sort by process order
'
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("zpr2013b").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("zpr2013b").Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range(Cells(1, "D"), Cells(nLastRow, "D")), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("zpr2013b").Sort
    .SetRange Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(nLastRow, "q"))
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

wtTot = Cells(2, "B").Value

'
'go top to bottom and put the total weight of each process order
'in the row of the last coil produced
'
For nRow = 2 To nLastRow
    If Cells(nRow, "D").Value = Cells(nRow + 1, "D").Value Then
        wtTot = wtTot + Cells(nRow + 1, "B").Value
    Else
        Cells(nRow, "E").Value = wtTot
        wtTot = Cells(nRow + 1, "B").Value
    End If
Next nRow

'
'go bottom to top and fill in all the blanks of the other coils
'
For x = nLastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(x, "E").Value = "" Then
        Cells(x, "E").Value = Cells(x + 1, "E").Value
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding `Application.Screenupdating = False` at the top of your code (after `Sub FillInTotalWeight`), and `Application.Screenupdating = True` at the bottom, before `End Sub`.  This may speed up your code a little.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this code instead. It should run much faster for you and will accomplish the same thing:

```
Sub FillInTotalWeight()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("zpr2013b")

    ws.UsedRange.Sort Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Columns("D")), xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    With Range("E2", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(, 1))
        .Formula = "=SUMIF(D:D,D" & .Row & ",B:B)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```